# With Spring how can I execute code after HIbernate is initialized but before the application starts?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to insert some data into the database using the application API if the application has started up with some empty database tables. How do I go about this?

I'm using Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4.1.1.

[edit]

Thanks to AlexR the answer is to sublcass `ContextLoaderListener`, call super in `contextInitialized` and then do whatever it is you need to do:

```
public class MyContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event) {

        super.contextInitialized(event);
        // ... doStuff();
    }

}
```

You may also need to wire this up in web.xml instead of the Spring one:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MyContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use spring context listener.
Take a look on: http://fusesource.com/docs/framework/2.2/deploy_guide/CXFServletDeploySpring.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?88896-Spring-MVC-3-is-ContextLoaderListener-needed